# Magento get list of products which never ordered

Tags: magento-1.8, php, mysql

I am using magento 1.8 and want to generate a list of products which never ordered on our site. Can you please give some idea on it. I am open to use any code as well as any sql which can be directly run on our database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first identify the products ordered:

```
$orderedItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
$orderedProductsIds = array(-1); //add a -1 to have at least one element
foreach ($orderedItems as $item) {
    $orderedProductIds[] = $item->getProductId();
}
```

Then get the product collection excluding the result above.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$orderedProductIds));
```

Then do what you need with the products that result.
For example, build an array with skus and names:
$products = array();

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $products[$product->getSku()] = $product->getName();
}
//do what you want with `$products`
```

Comment: I am getting `$orderedProductsIds` but `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()` is not working for me.

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: aah, it's my mistake that I did not add `addAttributeToSelect` beacuse I have configurable products only. Now it's working like charm.

Comment: Boy, you save my day. You are so quick and accurate.